# How to make ListView/DataView responsive in bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm making my first webshop. I want to load all my products from my sql database onto my page. so I use a listvieuw. but it is not responsive. I want my products next to each other on a medium screen and under each other on a small size screen like a phone

I tried to use bootstrap class's like "row" but now every new generated "template" is a row and they wil stand under each other on every screen size..if that makes sense?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductNaam") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
                <div><%#Eval("ProductName") %></div>
                <br />
                <br />

                <div><%#Eval("description") %></div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div><%#Eval("price") %></div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection objCn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            objCn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                objCmd.Connection = objCn;
                objCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TblProducten;";

                objCn.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                Adapter.SelectCommand = objCmd;

                DataSet Myds = new DataSet();
                Adapter.Fill(Myds);

                ListView1.DataSource = Myds;
                ListView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

I expected it to be responsive but it was not like I had already described

Comment: _"I want my products next to each other on a medium screen and under each other on a small size screen like a phone"_ - It doesn't sound like you've done your due-diligence in reviewing the Bootstrap documentation regarding grid structure: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Please update your question with what markup you've tried, as your question is relatively generic and a direct answer is not possible.

Comment: I know the grid system and I know how it works, but if I apply bootstrap to what is in the <ItemTemplate> it does not work ... the ListVieuw always puts it under each other and i only want that to happen on a small size screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your "asp:ListView" in a div with the "row" class, then use the grid system columns to get the behavior you want.

The example below should help you to get started:

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-sm-4 border p-3">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductNaam") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
                <div><%#Eval("ProductName") %></div>
                <br />
                <br />

                <div><%#Eval("description") %></div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div><%#Eval("price") %></div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

As @Ben already mentioned, read the bootstrap docs around this subject:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/